# How to get the TCP stream number with a listener?

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I an analysing a very large PCAP holding many HTTP transactions, some of which interest me. I am using `tshark` with a Lua script essentially to query all packets that match a filter.

```
tshark -X lua_script:filter.lua -r some.pcap  -q
```

So far so good. However, I am looking specifically for the value of a packet's TCP stream number which goes by the name `tcp.stream` inside Wireshark. Can anyone say what changes I require to `filter.lua` to print that?

```
-- filter.lua
do
    local function init_listener()
        local tap = Listener.new("http","http contains someKeyValue && tcp.port eq 1234")
        function tap.reset()
        end
        function tap.packet(pinfo,tvb,ip)
            print("Found my packet ... now what?")
        end
        function tap.draw()
        end
    end
    init_listener()
end
```

The documentation on what `pinfo`, `tvb` and `ip` *are* is unforthcoming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the TCP stream number through a `Field`.

```
local tcp_stream = Field.new("tcp.stream").value
```

The value of the `Field` is the value for the current packet. You don't need to create a new `Field` each time. This allows you to make the `Field` a constant and create a function that returns the TCP stream number of the current packet. It is also possible to call the `Field` value to get the `FieldInfo` value which may include additional useful information.

You want the `filter.lua` to look like:

```
-- filter.lua
do
    local function init_listener()
        local get_tcp_stream = Field.new("tcp.stream")
        local tap = Listener.new("http","http contains someKeyValue && tcp.port eq 1234")
        function tap.reset()
        end
        function tap.packet(pinfo,tvb,ip)
            print(tostring(get_tcp_stream()))
        end
        function tap.draw()
        end
    end
    init_listener()
end
```

https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Field.html#lua_class_Field